# Are DRM/TTM Linux kernel module needed for a virtual machine with no graphical interface?

Tags: debian, kernel-modules, vmware, modprobe

In a VMware virtual machine, I have a Debian 11 with no graphical interface (but with an SSH server).
I try to blacklist some unneeded kernel modules, like everything related to Bluetooth, HDMI, serial mouse and so.

But for [DRM/TTM][1], I'm not sure of me: at first glance, I would say there is no need for a module managing the 3D of my graphical card. So I would blacklist the following in `/etc/modprobe.d/my-blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist vmwgfx
blacklist drm_kms_helper
blacklist ttm
blacklist drm
```

(before doing a `update-initramfs -u` do update the initramfs for next boot)

But I wonder if my Linux distribution is natively made to use the GPU to do some calculation, to help the CPU, and if disabling the DRM would break this? And does this has a sense for virtual environments, as the GPU of a VM is mainly managed by the CPU of the hypervisor?

[1]: [https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/gpu/drm-mm.html#:~:text=TTM%20was%20the%20first%20DRM,i.e.%20most%20discrete%20video%20cards](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/gpu/drm-mm.html#:%7E:text=TTM%20was%20the%20first%20DRM,i.e.%20most%20discrete%20video%20cards)).

Answer (score 0):

> Are DRM/TTM Linux kernel module needed for a virtual machine with no graphical interface?

No.

> But I wonder if my Linux distribution is natively made to use the GPU to do some calculation

Linux distros currently don't properly and fully utilize the GPU and in console mode it's not used at all.

> and if disabling the DRM would break this?

Nothing will break.